# Edge taskbar pinned shortcut is not in a standard location

Tags: windows, taskbar, shortcuts, microsoft-edge

I'm on Windows 10. According to [this](https://superuser.com/a/58625/332179) answer the standard location for taskbar pinned shortcuts is `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`. I indeed can find all my taskbar pinned apps there (including Internet Explorer) except Microsoft Edge.

Where can I find taskbar pinned shortcut for Edge?

Comment: The shortcut for Microsoft Edge works a bit differently, since it a [UWP application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform).  You can find a more in-depth explanation (including how to create another Edge shortcut) within [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1191087/650163).

Comment: @Run5k: Thank you for pointing to the close question on this. However, I'm still not sure if it's possible to edit taskbar pinned shortcut for Edge.

Comment: We are always glad to help.  That being said, your original question didn't say anything about your desire to *"edit taskbar pinned shortcut for Edge."*  If that was your ultimate goal, it's important to state that within your question.  You can still potentially edit your question to emphasize that, and hopefully someone else will chime in with a viable method to achieve your goal.